How to make multiple plots of several columns from a Pandas dataframe?
Suppose I have a dataframe like this with columns year, months, max, min:
year  Month   max   mix
2000    1   3.0    0.30
2000    2   3.7   0.70
2000    3   3.6    0.60
2001    1   2.4   1.40
2001    2  2.9  1.30
2001    3  3.1  1.55`
So for each year I have 12 months, and for each month I have or more columns holding numerical data. For each year separately I'd like to make a plot showing how max and min values vary with each month. In the example here, I have 2 years (2000 and 200) so I need 2 separate plots, showing 2 line graphs (or bars) on each, corresponding to max and min columns (vertical axis) and "month" variable on horizontal.
How can I do this? Ideally I'd like a line plot (so 2 lines, max and min ), but a bar plot is ok too. I just need an explanation as to how to implement this.

Minimal code!!?

(Note that at StackOverflow, you are supposed to add some minimal code. StackOverflow is not meant as free coding service.) To create the type of plots you suggest, seaborn (a library that extends matplotlib) is the often easier.  E.g using lmplot: sns.lmplot(data, x='month', y='min', col='year', col_wrap=3, fit_reg=False).

Here is one approach
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {
    'year': [2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001],
    'Month': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3],
    'max': [3.0, 3.7, 3.6, 2.4, 2.9, 3.1],
    'min': [0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 1.4, 1.3, 1.55]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

years = df['year'].unique()

for year in years:
    plt.figure()
    year_data = df[df['year'] == year]
    plt.plot(year_data['Month'], year_data['max'], label='Max', marker='o')
    plt.plot(year_data['Month'], year_data['min'], label='Min', marker='o')
    plt.title(f'Year {year}')
    plt.xlabel('Month')
    plt.ylabel('Values')
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()

which retunrs



Use .groupby for cleaner code.
